# Compare two lists of class objects and keep the difference and the equals in Python

Tags: python, class, list-comprehension

I'm currently stuck and i hope someone here can help me out. What I am trying to achieve is following: I have two APIs, those deliver me each a list of learning courses represented as python class instance. At one side there is the MS Learn API and the workflow is that I get them, map the data and insert them in my database. But before I do this I want to check for 1.) duplicated courses and 2.) if there is a duplicate - is it maybe newer then my saved course in my database? And 3.) Do I have courses in my database that are not existing in the MS Learn Course List?

The attributes I need to check are the "referenceID" for dupes / non existing courses on external side and the "created_at" if something is newer / older. Instead of wild looping and saving values in different list I would like to use something more clean and pythonic like a custom **eq** function and then comparing the whole two lists of class objects and keeping 1. all new courses, removing the dupes from the list and 2. the difference that is not existing in the list for external courses so I can delete them

Sorry for the long text here’s some code:

```
@dataclass
class Courses:
    id: str
    title: str
    description: str
    courseUrl: str
    referenceId: str
    providerId: int
    publishingState: str
    createdAt: str
    updatedAt: str
```

First try of an custom **eq** func - never used that before idk if this would work:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Courses):
        return self.title == other.title \
               and self.description == other.description \
               and self.courseUrl == other.courseUrl \
               and self.referenceId == other.referenceId \
               and self.providerId == other.providerId \
               and self.publishingState == other.publishingState \
               and self.createdAt == other.createdAt \
               and self.updatedAt == other.updatedAt

    return False
```

First start of my looping chaos:

```
    internal_courses = get_courses(request)
    internal_reference_ids = []
    duplicated_courses = []

    for int_course in internal_courses:
        internal_reference_ids.append(int_course.referenceId)

    for ext_course in external_courses:
        if ext_course.referenceId in internal_reference_ids:
            duplicated_courses.append(ext_course)
            external_courses.remove(ext_course)
```

Thank you very much in advance, I am exited to learn something new :)

Answer (score 0):

Your defined `__eq__` method enables you to compare class instances like this:

```
if course_a == course_b:
    # Do something
```

When comparing two lists, you call `list.__eq__` method instead. If this list contains your Courses objects (btw, you should use singular form, as it is single Course), they will be compared using your defined `__eq__` method.
This means, that you can just compare `[course_a, course_b] == [course_a, course_c]` and it should work as you intented.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
      
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.arg1 == other.arg1 and self.arg2 == other.arg2
      
# Initialize two instances with identical arguments.
one = Example('x', 'y')
two = Example('x', 'y')

print(one == two)   # True

a = [one]
b = [two]

print(a == b)   # Also True
```

P.S.
Check out `@dataclass(eq=True)` as it does pretty much the same thing